# Elixir/Phoenix add a. related entity to an existing one via form

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am quite new to elixir/phoenix and I am struggeling a bit with a concept. I have found a workaround, but I am not happy with it.

Context:
I have created a "project" in my database. Now I would like to create a "work item" that is related to the project via the projects "show" page. Since it is related to that particular project I need to add the ID to the changeset.

I tried doing this in the `projects_controller` like so:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    project   = Clients.get_project!(id)
    changeset = Clients.change_work_item(%BudgetItem{project_id: project.id})
    render(conn, "show.html", project: project, changeset: changeset)
  end
```

This is the form:

```
%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%= if @changeset.action do %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.</p>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= label f, :title %>
  <%= text_input f, :title %>
  <%= error_tag f, :title %>

  <%= label f, "duration" %>
  <%= number_input f, :amount_in_cents %>
  <%= error_tag f, :amount_in_cents %>

  <div>
    <%= submit "Save" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I hit submit the `project_id` is not in the changeset that ends up in my `work_item_controller` - my understanding is that this is because of the immutability of the data in elixir. My workaround is now that I have a hidden field in the view that "stores" the project_id (`<%= hidden_input f, :project_id %>`). This works, but I am unhappy with it, because the user can meddle with it and well - it feels wrong to "misuse" the view to do this. Can any of you by any chance explain to me how this is usually done? I have been unable to find a satisfying solution.

Let me know if you need more code to better understand the implementation.

Thanks for your time!

Edit:

```
defmodule SthWeb.WorkItemController do
  use SthWeb, :controller

  alias Sth.Clients
  alias Sth.Clients.Project

  def create(conn, %{"work_item" => work_item_params}) do
    case Clients.create_work_item(work_item_params) do
      {:ok, work_item} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Budget increased successfully!")
        |> redirect(to: Routes.project_path(conn, :show, work_item.project_id))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Something went wrong.")
        |> redirect(to: Routes.project_path(conn, :show, 1))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the good setup to deal with your situation.
Your project_id comes from the path where the user is, and in your controller you just find for the existence of this project in the database. All of that looks good.
But the thing is your `show` you don't need this code `changeset = Clients.change_work_item(%BudgetItem{project_id: project.id})` just render a changeset with your BudgetItem like this: `changeset = Clients.change_work(%BudgetItem{})`. Now on the post action of the controller related to this, which you have not posted you can use the id sent to your controller to find the project and create an associated work item using `build_assoc`. If you could send your code in the post controller and the Clients context it could be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @franck - I have added the controller as well. The thing is - this is a different controller `work_item_controller` the show is in the the `projects_controller`. I could not for the life of me figure out where to get the project ID - please enlighten me, I was going nuts :)

Comment: The edit looks good with the controller.
Now you have to take also the id of your project in the work_item_controller. `def create(conn, %{"id" => project_id, "work_item" => work_item_params})`. You then get the project using your `Clients.get_project!(project_id)`. Lastly you send to the project to `Clients.create_work_item(project, work_item_params)`. In the function you can assign the work_item using the `put_assoc`. Hope it helps